# Installing git on an old Mac (10.6.8)

Tags: git, macos

After having read quite a few discussion on this topic I have realized that recent version of git seems not working on old mac.
I am using a intelcoreduo mini mac 2006 (10.6.8) in which I have python 2.7.9 is installed. However if try to detect the git version installed (2.5.3) by typing 
"git --version"
on Terminal, I get the message Illegal instruction
I have tried to instal different versions of git but the only one that seems good enough (according to several threads) is 1.8.4.2 that unfortunately is not available in the "installer mode".
I have therefore downloaded git-1.8.4.2.tar.gz that I don't know how to handle it.
Is there anyone around so kind to tell me step by step what to do and/or if there is another solution to the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) - they support all the way back to 10.5 apparently.

Comment: done. I have installed brew directly from the terrminal. Thanks. Now, back to the basics I see that to make Brew working I have to prompt a command to pick Git from somewhere (the .gz from my desktop or directly from the web?) and install it. I really don't know much about what to do. I am installing these tools because I want to take an online course about python. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Once you have Homebrew installed you can just do `brew install git` from the command line.

Comment: I tried to do it as follows. 1) copied the .gz file onto  ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew 2) brew install git

Comment: sorry I did it before your hint. However this is the message I got "### 100,0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.1
==> make install"   After a while I tested it "minimac:~ user$ git --version
git version 2.6.0"
It seems ok. Can I delete the .gz from /Homebrew now?

Comment: OK - you shouldn't need to copy .gz files anywhere - Homebrew takes care of everything for you - it's a complete package manager which downloads the code, builds it and installs it. Anyway, yes, delete the .gz file and carry on. BTW you might want to look at some of the other packages available via Homebrew - there's a lot of useful stuff other than git.

Comment: thanks a lot. If you have some hints where to get them (and more than everything a good tutorial to learn the very very very basics) I'd appreciate.

Comment: Just look at the intro on http://brew.sh - scroll down on the home page and read - you can easily list all the available packages and then install anything that looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an old OSX like me (10.6.8), go to this site:
[Homebrew website](http://brew.sh/)

and install it with this command:'

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Now, try to got to :
[Git OS X Installer website](https://mackyle.github.io/git-osx-installer/)
and install from there the GIT.
Hope this helps !

But I had some errors. And fix them by using this simple, amazing little script from the fella Moncef Belyamani @:
[Moncef Belyamani](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)

and works like a charm.
Here is the link to his script(customizable!!) @[GitHUb](https://github.com/monfresh/laptop)

Now, if I do:
git --version 
it reports:
git version 2.8.4

Great ! Wish you Luck too!

Comment: Doesn't Brew need xcode and the latest xcode can't be installed on an old mac (2016) with 10.6.8?  Also, doesn't brew need git? I have brew installed but when I do "brew install git", I get "undefined method '>=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Dig it:
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Installation.md#installation

Answer (score 0):

this worked for my mac os x 10.4 (lol, very old)

http://mackyle.github.io/git-osx-installer/